# Why are all my total scores for tags 0?

Tags: discussion, tags

On my Meta Stack Overflow profile all total scores for tags are shown as 0, but the tooltip shows the right total score, see:

[image]

But I can see the right total score for other users.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Aren't tag scores based on **answers**? So, no upvoted answers, no score?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Oh, your are right. I have no answer. I didn't know that the total score is only based on answers.

Comment: @Glorfindel: The OP of the other post already knows, that only answers count, but I didn't know it. So the question is different, but sure the accepted answer matches also my question. I'm not sure, if that matches the definition of a duplicate.

Comment: @dur I know, but the *answer* to that question still answers this question.

Comment: @Glorfindel:  I'm not so sure this is a good dupe.  On the one hand, it *would* have told the OP if the tooltip had shown the second part of the statement; on the other, the tooltip doesn't indicate what the answer score is if it doesn't exist.  Perhaps the fact that the tooltip doesn't show is a bug on its own?

Comment: @Makoto: If the tooltip had shown the answer score of 0, I would not have ask this question. I would not say, it is a bug, but perhaps a missing feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tag scores only track answer scores, not question scores.  This is *not* a bug.

[You have *no* answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/5277820/dur?tab=answers) on Meta, so it makes sense that your tag scores are zero there.

Answer (score 0):

You have have like 7 questions/answers and answers have no upvote

Also upvote on questions doesn't count